# Plugin retrieve multiple CRM dynamics Online 2015

Tags: c#, plugins, crm

I have a plugin with 1 steps (RetrieveMultiple) who run for My entity list. (results are OK and the data are filtred)
When i create a graphic (standard graphic on dynamics crm ) based on de the same entity, i noticed than the data on the graphic are not filtred
did someone know if is normal ?
is there any solution to have data filtred by the same plugin ?
thx for your help

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

I know what you are talking about because I had similar task and I have to say that charts in CRM don't use RetrieveMultiple method for getting of data. So the only solution I see for you is to properly configure views and security for records that are used to display information in charts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.In my case i have lote of charts on several entities.So there is no solution to synchronize charts and views (use the same records in associeted views to construct charts) by modifying the plugin code that is used to filter records displayed on views  ?

Comment: Since I firstly answered your question nothing has been changed.